Loss is not decreasing
I'm building a project on text generation using transformer architecture. I've used Huggingface tokenizer for tokenization, my dataset is daily-dialog, and my model architecture is:
class languageModel(nn.Module):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.encoder_embedding_layer = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, n_embd)
    self.encoder_positional_encoder = PositionalEncoding(n_embd, block_size)
    

    self.decoder_embedding_layer = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, n_embd)
    self.decoder_positional_encoder = PositionalEncoding(n_embd, block_size)
    
    self.transformer = nn.Transformer(n_embd, n_head, num_encoder_layers=6, num_decoder_layers=6, activation="gelu", device=device, norm_first=True)
    self.fin = nn.Linear(n_embd, vocab_size)

def forward(self, encoder_idx, decoder_idx, target=None, encoder_attention_mask=None, decoder_attention_mask=None):
    B, T = encoder_idx.shape
    
    encoder_embed = self.encoder_embedding_layer(encoder_idx)
    enc = self.encoder_positional_encoder(encoder_embed)  # Shape: (1, T, n_embd)
    
    B, T = decoder_idx.shape
    decoder_embed = self.decoder_embedding_layer(decoder_idx)
    decoder_idx = self.decoder_positional_encoder(decoder_embed)
    
    output = self.transformer(enc, decoder_idx, src_key_padding_mask=encoder_attention_mask, tgt_key_padding_mask=decoder_attention_mask)
    return self. Fin(output)

and my training block look like this:
model = languageModel().to(device)
model.apply(init_weights)
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=1000, gamma=0.9)
itrs = 0
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
num_batches = data["input_ids"].size(0)
batch_losses = []
for epoch in range(5):
  for i in range(num_batches):
    encoder_idx = data["input_ids"][i].to(device)
    decoder_idx = data["target_inputs"][i].to(device)
    targets = data["target_labels"][i].to(device)
    encoder_attention_mask = data["attention_mask"][i].to(device).transpose(1, 0)
    decoder_attention_mask = data["target_attention_mask"][i].to(device).transpose(1, 0)
    
    batch_size, seq_len = encoder_idx.shape
    
    output = model(encoder_idx, decoder_idx, targets, encoder_attention_mask, decoder_attention_mask)
    mask = targets != tokenizer.eos_token_id
    loss = criterion(output.view(-1, vocab_size)[mask.view(-1)], targets[mask].view(-1))
    batch_losses.append(loss.item())
    if i%500 == 0 or math.isnan(loss.item()):
        current_lr = optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] 
        print(f"Iteration {i}, Learning Rate: {current_lr}, Loss: {loss}")
    optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
    loss.backward()
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
    optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
    if i == 6300:
        break
print("Epoch done")

loss gradualy decreases from ~11 to ~5 but then fluctuate on 5. How can i decrease it further?
I've already tried changing optimizer between AdamW, Adagrad, SGD and also tried gredient clipping but the problem is still there.
